# load a new component on button click in ReactJs?

Tags: reactjs, components

load a new component on button click in ReactJs?

Comment: Hi, can you describe your problem more in deep?
Maybe you can give some of your current state and what you want to achieve

Comment: Please give me a solution added problem deeply @WesleyLoh

Answer (score 2):

I have fixed your code. Please check this example below:

**MasterCreate Component**

```
import MasterIncident from './MasterIncident';
import MasterAddPage from './MasterAddPage';
import React from "react";

class MasterCreate extends React.Component {
    state = {
        renderView: 0
    };

    clickBtn = (value) => {
        this.setState({
            renderView: value
        });
    };

    render() {
        switch (this.state.renderView) {
            case 1:
                return <MasterAddPage value={"Master Add Page is added"}/>;
            default:
                return <MasterIncident clickBtn={this.clickBtn}/>;
        }
    }
}
export default MasterCreate;
```

**MasterIncident Component**

```
import React from "react";

class MasterIncident extends React.Component {
    render() {
        console.log('master incident');
        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                <button
                    variant="contained"
                    size="medium"
                    color="primary"
                    value="single"
                    name="1"
                    onClick={() => {this.props.clickBtn(0)}}
                >
                    Add
                </button>
                <button
                    variant="contained"
                    size="medium"
                    color="primary"
                    value="batch"
                    name="2"
                    onClick={() => {this.props.clickBtn(1)}}
                >
                    Export
                </button>
                <h3>Master Incident Inventory</h3>
            </React.Fragment>
        );
    }
}
export default MasterIncident;
```

**MasterAddPage Component**

```
import React from "react";

const MasterAddPage = (props) => {
    console.log(props);
    return (
        <div>Content</div>
    )
};
export default MasterAddPage;
```

Comment: I tried this code but I facing this same error 

TypeError: Class constructor MasterIncident cannot be invoked without 'new'

Comment: @ssaran, I have successfully run this code from my machine. Please create a simple component for showing "hello world" and check that whether it runs or not on your machine.

Comment: Another one help master Add page I have one close button if clicks go to Master incident page

Comment: @ssaran, that means you want to go back when you click on close button. for going back , you need to use history and you can check this example and can implement this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61643881/react-router-5-1-uselocation-hook-determine-past-locations/61645454#61645454

Answer (score 2):

instead of doing this?

```
  render() {
    switch (this.state.renderView) {
      case 1:
        return <MasterAddPage />;
      default:
        return <MasterIncident clickBtn={this.clickBtn} />;
    }
  }
```

you can do this:

```
  render() {
    return (
      this.state.renderView === 0 ? <MasterAddPage /> : <MasterIncident clickBtn={this.clickBtn} />
    )
  }
```