# useLocation hook - determine past locations

Tags: reactjs, react-router

According to React Router 5.1 [documentation](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/location) it should be possible to see "where the app is now, where you want it to go, or even where it was". In my app I need to see "where it was" - what locations I have visited **before** landing at a specific location.

More precisely; I wish to find a previous location matching a certain pattern. That location might be two or three locations ago.

However - I cannot figure out how to perform this.

What is a recommended approach to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I turns out the best way, for me, to see where the application has been been is to simply use the state property in the [React Router Link](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/Link).

[This article](https://tylermcginnis.com/react-router-pass-props-to-components/) on how to pass state from `Link` to components really helped explain how to use the `Link` state.

Basically the `Link` can pass the state property to the rendered component.

```
<Link to={{ pathname: "/courses", state: { fromDashboard: true } }} />
```

The rendered component then access the state via `props.location.state`

This in conjunction with passing props to components generating the links solved my problem!

Answer (score 0):

In React Router you can use the goBack() method if you need to react a previous path in your history. Also, there is a possibility to push your path to history state, but that’s only needed if you need to know the URL of the previous location.

You can read more about this functionality from here: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/history

Comment: Hi Joakim! Thank you for the reply. I do not simply wish to goBack(). Rather looking back in time to find locations matching a pattern. Cannot see how push() applies, but will definately take a closer look at pushing path to history state. (^__^)/ Kind regards /K

Comment: Ah, so I can push() to history, but how can I obtain all pushed history (array of previous locations)? Kind regards /K

Answer (score 0):

You can check this example. Hope it helps you.

```
import React from "react";
import {BrowserRouter as Router,Switch,Route,Link} from "react-router-dom";
import { withRouter } from "react-router";

export default function BasicExample() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <Link to="/">Home</Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link to="/about">About</Link>
          </li>
        </ul>

        <hr />
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/">
            <Home />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/about">
            <About />
          </Route>
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}

function Home() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Home</h2>
    </div>
  );
}

const About = withRouter(({history, ...props}) => (
  <h1 {...props}>
    About
    <hr/>
    <button onClick={() => {history.push('/')}}>go back</button>
  </h1>
));
```

**Another Example for going back -2**

```
import React from "react";
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route, Link} from "react-router-dom";
import {withRouter} from "react-router";

export default function BasicExample() {
    return (
        <Router>
            <div>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <Link to="/">Home</Link>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <Link to="/about">About</Link>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <Link to="/about/insideabout">Inside About</Link>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <hr/>
                <Switch>
                    <Route exact path="/">
                        <Home/>
                    </Route>
                    <Route exact path="/about">
                        <About/>
                    </Route>
                    <Route path="/about/insideabout">
                        <InsideAbout/>
                    </Route>
                </Switch>
            </div>
        </Router>
    );
}

function Home() {
    return (
        <div>
            <h2>Home</h2>
        </div>
    );
}

const About = withRouter(({history, ...props}) => (
    <div>
        <h1>
            About
            <hr/>
            <button onClick={() => {
                // history.push('/')
                history.goBack(-1);
            }}>go back
            </button>
        </h1>
    </div>
));

const InsideAbout = withRouter(({history, ...props}) => (
    <h1 {...props}>
        Inside About
        <hr/>

        <button onClick={() => {
            history.goBack();
        }}>go back
        </button>
        <button onClick={() => {
            history.go(-2);
        }}>go home
        </button>
    </h1>
));
```

Comment: Thanks! That would be the case if I did *always* come from "/" when landing on "/about". In my case I could have landed on "/about" from four different locations. In some cases I would need to go(-2) to arrive at the correct page - and I need to know when to go(-1) or go(-2) or go(-3) or to another page altogether. Kind regards /K

Comment: @Kermit, I have added another example. Please check it. hope it fulfil your requirement.